# Test class is not visible. Can I not call a test class from a separate test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my question. I am getting near the end of finally testing my new trigger, and started to clean up my code. I decided(as recommended by others in this community) to create a separate class that contains methods to fill Accounts, Opportunities and other objects. However, when I call the class and it's method I get the error: ***Type is not visible***

This is my class with the methods described above.

```
@isTest
public class TestUtil 
{
    public static Contact initContact(){
    /**
        *   Create a Contact
        *   Insert Contact into DB
        *   Return Contact back into testPage in order to use information
    **/             
        Contact testContact = new Contact (
                    firstName = 'Firstly', lastName = 'Lastly', email = 'test@test.com'
                    );
        insert testContact;
        return testContact;
    }
```

My test class calling this:

```
@isTest
private class Test_Trig_Opportunity_CreateServContract {                
    static testMethod void testTriggerOpp() {
        //  Initiliazed Class that contains methods to create SF Objects(Account, Opportunity, etc. )
      TestUtil initObj = new TestUtil();    
        //initialize test variables (called from test variable class)        
      Contact testContact = initObj.initContact();
```

I also tried without calling the class at first:

```
@isTest
private class Test_Trig_Opportunity_CreateServContract {                
    static testMethod void testTriggerOpp() {               
        //initialize test variables (called from test variable class)        
     Contact testContact = TestUtil.initContact();
```

Both bring the same error. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Second one (with just a call to static method) should work fine 1st one is an overkill ;) Does it say which Type is not visible? Does `initContact()` look exactly like this? Isn't marked private or with some System.runAs? Did `TestUtil` save succesfully to server?

Comment: Your test passed in my DE org. I had to add the closing curly braces, but otherwise the second option worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Brad and eyescream for your responses. It helped me figure out that it was user error and I needed to compile the testclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you're second attempt is correct.  Since your initContact() method is static you don't need to initialize an instance of TestUtil to access it, i.e. `TestUtil.initContact()`

If you're still getting the method visibility issue you should log a case with support.  I've been using that exact same technique for the past 5 years and haven't had any issues, so it sounds like you may have hit a bug.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, the error was user error. I needed to run the TestUtil class first and then run the other class after. I figured since it 'Run Tests' it would have run everything.

Comment: Nice work figuring it out, best of luck with the project